# Variables not passing to class (PHP)

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a JSON response from an external API to a class in a different file. Somehow it's not storing in the class. I've tried var_dumping the class like this:

`$user->country_ip = $country_ip;
die(var_dump($user->country_ip));`

It somehow doesn't work. But, when I try to vardump the actual variable like this:

```
die(var_dump($country_ip));
```

Then it does work, so the variable is fine. I'm very confused, does anyone have an answer to this? It's midnight here, it might be something small?

Comment: your user class has the public variable `country_ip`?

Comment: What do you mean? The variable itself is global and accessible throughout the entire file

Comment: I've added an example for you, Have a look there

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work" means? I used that same code and it dumped the value as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimalist example will be like this,

```
class User
{
  public $country_ip;

  public function getCountryIp()
  {
    return json_decode($this->country_ip, true);
  }
}

$country_ip = '192.168.2.227';
$user = new User();
$user->country_ip= json_encode($country_ip);
var_dump($user->getCountryIp()); //It will print "192.168.2.227"
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/YSk9X

Comment: The function is not within the class, it's actually in a different file. Does that make a difference? I have obviously created the class, etc. And it works with all my other variables which I post towards the file.

It just doesn't seem to work with this variable from a new function?

Comment: Nvm! Your answer worked! Thanks a lot man, I just overlooked the public part and forgot to do it for the country_ip variable